# I cannot get my site to show on a reverse proxy NginX server

Tags: django, nginx, supervisord

I am trying to deploy a Django website on a VPS and I have everything set up in terms of the following:

1. The app runs if I use the development server and I go to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8000
2. Nginx is running because if I go to the site at founderslooking.com I can see the nginx server page.
3. I am following the instructions from a video as this is my first time doing it and I have set up supervisor. I have the following conf file set up so I can use nginx as a reverse proxy but clearly this is not working because I do not see my site. I checked and supervisor is running.

/etc/nginx/sites-available/founders.conf:

```
upstream founders_app_server {
        server unix:/websapps/founders/founders_3_10_12/run/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name api.founderslooking.com;
        client_max_body_size 4G;
        location / {
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_redirect off;
                if (!-f $request_filename){
                        proxy_pass http://founders_app_server;
                }
        }
}
```

If I change the server name to founderslooking.com then I get a bad gateway if I go to founderslooking.com

/etc/supervisor/conf.d/founders.conf:

```
[program:founders]

command = /webapps/founders/founders_3_10_12/bin/gunicorn_start
user = userfounders
stdout_logfile = /webapps/founders/founders_3_10_12/logs/supervisor.log
redirect_stderr = true
environment=LANG=en_US.UTF-8,LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

Not sure what else to include here but I checked and nginx is running, supervisor is running and I presume if supervisor is running then the app is also running.

Any help to sort this out so I can see my site would be greatly appreciated thanks

Here is the supervisor log file I don't see anything wrong. Why is deploying a django app so difficult?

```
Starting
[2023-10-10 09:10:56 +0000] [806] [DEBUG] Current configuration:
  config: ./gunicorn.conf.py
  wsgi_app: None
  bind: ['unix:/webapps/founders/founders_3_10_12/run/gunicorn.sock']
  backlog: 2048
  workers: 3
  worker_class: sync
  threads: 1
  worker_connections: 1000
  max_requests: 0
  max_requests_jitter: 0
  timeout: 30
  graceful_timeout: 30
  keepalive: 2
  limit_request_line: 4094
  limit_request_fields: 100
  limit_request_field_size: 8190
  reload: False
  reload_engine: auto
  reload_extra_files: []
  spew: False
  check_config: False
  print_config: False
  preload_app: False
  sendfile: None
  reuse_port: False
  chdir: /webapps/founders/founders_3_10_12/backend
  daemon: False
  raw_env: []
  pidfile: None
  worker_tmp_dir: None
  user: 998
  group: 999
  umask: 0
  initgroups: False
  tmp_upload_dir: None
  secure_scheme_headers: {'X-FORWARDED-PROTOCOL': 'ssl', 'X-FORWARDED-PROTO': 'https', 'X-FORWARDED-SSL': 'on'}
  forwarded_allow_ips: ['127.0.0.1']
  accesslog: None
  disable_redirect_access_to_syslog: False
  access_log_format: %(h)s %(l)s %(u)s %(t)s "%(r)s" %(s)s %(b)s "%(f)s" "%(a)s"
  errorlog: -
  loglevel: debug
  capture_output: False
  logger_class: gunicorn.glogging.Logger
  logconfig: None
  logconfig_dict: {}
  logconfig_json: None
  syslog_addr: udp://localhost:514
  syslog: False
  syslog_prefix: None
  syslog_facility: user
  enable_stdio_inheritance: False
  statsd_host: None
  dogstatsd_tags:
  statsd_prefix:
"supervisor.log" 222L, 8705B
```

I see this error in the error log but it makes no sense because that file exists and the user running the gunicorn process owns that folder and file. So why would it say the files does not exist?

```
2023/10/10 10:14:19 [crit] 689#689: *1 connect() to unix:/websapps/founders/founders_3_10_12/run/gunicorn.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 102.32.168.108, server: founderslooking.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/websapps/founders/founders_3_10_12/run/gunicorn.sock:/", host: "founderslooking.com"
```

here you can see it's there:

```
root@OhvcNSDb8D:/var/log/nginx# cd /webapps/founders/founders_3_10_12/run/
root@OhvcNSDb8D:/webapps/founders/founders_3_10_12/run# ls
gunicorn.sock
root@OhvcNSDb8D:/webapps/founders/founders_3_10_12/run#
```

Comment: Have you added the required dns entries, tested the nginx configurations, and enabled them?

Comment: Sorry not getting you on this. The domain works and you can go to founderslooking.com and you will see the nginx server. I am following a video and I did everything the guy explains. I created a symlink inside /etc/nginx/sites-enabled so not sure what else to do?

Comment: Read more in the {docs}(https://nginx.org/en/docs/). Test your configuration with `sudo nginx -t` and then reload your changes with `nginx -s reload`. Since I can see the default nginx website, you did not restart/reload anything.

Comment: I ran the test and it's successful. I restarted nginx and even did a reload I still see nginx server and not my app

Comment: Do you see the `founders.conf` file in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`? Btw. `api.found...` seems not to have a DNS entry and will not work.

Comment: There is a sym link to founders.conf in the /etc/nginx/sites-enabled. There is a founders.conf file in the sites-available directory. Yes I removed api.founderslooking.com and made it just founderslooking.com restarted nginx and now I get a bad gateway error if I go to founderslooking.com

Comment: Check service logs and see what is crashing.

Comment: I honestly don't know anymore I checked and I can see the site if I run the dev server. I can see the site if I run gunicorn but I cannot getv nginx to connect to the the app and display it.